# Continuous integration with SQL Source Control, SQL Automation Pack and Jenkins

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, jenkins

I need to realize continuous integration (CI) from one database to another one (from dev to stage).
I'm using such tools as SQL Source Control, SQL Automation Pack and Jenkins.

For example, we make some changes on dev. 
Using source control we commit our changes to the repository. 
In Jenkins a job was created, a build trigger was set up.

My job has two steps:

1) create a package from repository

`sqlCI.exe Build /scriptsFolder=. /packageId=NewCIPackage /packageVersion=1.%BUILD_NUMBER% /temporaryDatabaseServer=* /temporaryDatabaseUserName=* /temporaryDatabasePassword="*" /outputFolder=\tmp\packages`

after this step in \tmp\packages necessary package is created

2) update the existing stage db with the latest version in source control

`sqlCI.exe Sync /databaseName=test2 /temporaryDatabaseServer=*/temporaryDatabaseUserName=* /temporaryDatabasePassword="*" /package=\tmp\packages\NewCIPackage.1.%BUILD_NUMBER%.nupkg`

At first this variant worked, simple changes were integrated from dev to stage. But I faced a problem in the next case.

We have two tables on dev and stage:

`create table test (
    id int identity(1,1),
    col1 varchar(255),
    col2 varchar(255)
);`

`create table test2 (
    id int identity(1,1),
    col1 varchar(255)
);`

I fill TEST2 with data on stage db.

Then I want to add foreign key in TEST2. At first I make changes on dev db:

`alter table test2
add testId int not null;`

`alter table test2
add constraint fk2_test2_test FOREIGN KEY(testId)
references dbo.test (id);`

After commit while continuous integration in Jenkins I get message-error:

`Error: The column [testId] on table [dbo].[test2] must be added but has no default and does not allow NULL values.
The table must be rebuilt. If the table contains data then the deployment script will fail.`

As far as I understand, this mistake occurs, because on stage TEST2 is filled with data.

Can I manage without deleting data from this table?
Did anybody face such problem? Maybe anybody has any solutions, advices? Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: You can add the column without the foreign key constraint, then write a script that fills in the column with the appropriate data, and then add the foreign key constraint.

Comment: It means, that all users should remember/know about such situation and commit two times - firstly when you add column (then you also should fill this column with data), secondly commit when you add the foreign key.

Or you can remember when you'll get the mail with some mistake from Jenkins. 

Maybe I should add any additional steps in Jenkins job between 1st and 2d steps or any additional attributes for Sync?

Comment: It sounds like you're worried about data getting added during this process.  With changes like this, you normally take down the application to prevent additional data from being added.

Answer (score 0):

Steps are the same.
The first step in Jenkins job is creating NuGet package:

```
sqlCI.exe Build /scriptsFolder=<value1> /packageId=<value2> /packageVersion= <value3>  /temporaryDatabaseServer=<value4> /temporaryDatabaseUserName=** /temporaryDatabasePassword="*****" /outputFolder=<value5> /additionalCompareArgs="<options>"
```

The second step is updating necessary DB according to the latest virsion in the repository using an existing NuGet package:

```
sqlci.exe Sync /databaseName=<value1> /databaseServer=<value2> /databaseUserName=***** /databasePassword="*****" /package=<value3> /additionalCompareArgs="<options>"
```

For borth steps it's better to set up such option as /include:Identical in order to avoid build mistakes, if there're no changes.

Also we should remember that:

1. for foreign key should be determined the default value;
2. if the table is renamed, all data will be lost;
3. if static data are committed, data will be overwritten on stage;
4. for using linked servers DTC should be configured (or you can use dynamic queries)